# Using trigger to check the data if already exist in the table and block the insertion

Tags: oracle

I am trying to use trigger to check whether whether the plate number that user is inserting already exist or not.If found then display message insertion blocked. There were some errors but i cant solve it. Below is the script:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trig_check_plate_no
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF plate_number ON cars
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN(NEW.plate_number IS NOT NULL)

DECLARE 
vn_count NUMBER(10);

BEGIN 
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    INTO vn_count
    FROM cars
    WHERE plate_number = NEW.plate_number
    IF(:vn_count>0) 
        THEN DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Insertion blocked.');
        ELSE DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Data inserted.');
    END IF;
END trig_check_plate_no;
/
```

How can i solve it?

Comment: DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE is Oracle, is this question tagged correctly?

Comment: Create a unique index.

Comment: Create a unique index or (better) a unique constraint.  But to answer the (main) problem with your trigger -- you have your colons backwards.  You need a colon (:) in front of every occurrence of "NEW".  And you should't have one in front of "vn_count".

Answer (score 0):

In fact, you can't force a trigger to abort the operation that triggered its execution other than providing invalid values on purpose which is not a good style at all.

To achieve what you want to do, the easiest way would be to create a unique index on that table:

```
ALTER TABLE cars ADD CONSTRAINT c_plate_no UNIQUE ( plate_number );
```

Your DBMS should throw an error when you try to insert a value that already exists.

After doing so, you can omit your trigger entirely.

Comment: In my code there is error showing in NEW.plate_number. How to solve it? Its saying "identifier  NEW.plate_number must be declared".

Comment: My answer was related to mysql because the question was tagged so, however, a unique constraint should work in oracle as well.

Comment: `NEW.plate_number` is syntactically related to a trigger. You don't need a trigger at all when using a unique constraint (= unique index).